# 2005 Chevy Suburban 2wd 1500 Battery Drain tied to RTD 30 Amp Fuse for Air Ride Suspension

Tags: battery, battery-drain

I recently purchased replacement rear air shocks for my 2005 Suburban  along with a Dorman Air Shock Compressor. Prior to replacing the shocks I had replaced the compressor a year ago. A month ago my battery died- I found I had a parasitic drain that I traced to the 30 Amp RTD fuse controlling the system- it was drawing 3 AMPS when I did AMP test- when I pulled the fuse it dropped to near o amps. When I removed the fuse the battery did not drain, so I thought maybe the compressor was bad again- wiring etc.

I received a new compressor under warranty and ordered Arnott shocks AS 2715. I installed them fired her up and it worked as it should. Next morning battery is dead again- checked the fuse and it was still drawing over 3 Amps.

So what else in this system could be causing the parasitic drain? Like I stated once I remove the 30 AMP fuse for this system the battery does not die, so somewhere on this circuit I am getting a draw and I don't know what else is on this circuit other than the compressor?. What other electronic components are on this circuit that might cause the battery drain?

Comment: Is this factory air ride or aftermarket? There are probably other components on that 30 amp fuse that can cause a draw. I would suggest leaving the fuse in place, disconnecting the compressor, and see if you still have an amp draw. This will tell you if it is related to the compressor or not. If the draw goes away, you can start looking at the wiring/components within the air ride system. If it **does not** go away, then you have to look for something else within the 30 amp circuit.